# How to connect checkbox to box shadow so that It can remove check box with box shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Delete Checkbox" onclick="return deleteCheckbox('checkbox1','checkboxContainer')" />
  <script>
    var checkboxObject = document.getElementById(checkBoxID);
  </script>


  <div>
    <div class="checkbox-1">
      <div id="checkboxContainer"> <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
        <p>JVC200123
          <br>Acme DISC
          <br>1.00$
          <br>Size:700 MB</p>
        <script>
          checkboxObject = document.getElementById(checkBoxID);

          function deleteCheckbox(checkboxID, parentID, ) {

            var checkboxObject = document.getElementById(checkboxID);
            var parentObject = document.getElementById(parentID);

            parentObject.removeChild(checkboxObject);
          }
        </script>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: your question is unclear - you seem to want some CSS, but have posted none ... also `checkboxID` is undefined - you're also doing `checkboxObject = document.getElementById(checkBoxID);` three times ... why?

Comment: welcome, i turned your code into a snippet, it shows in the console errors that might explain your issue, unless those vars are defined in your own script. However , your checkbox gets removed allright

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

question is not so clear, in case your main porblem is with checkbox in javascript:

so your checkbox id is "checkbox1" :

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
```

but in js, you put this "checkboxID" which doesn't exist.

try:

```
var checkboxObject = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
```